# Why does my Excel Chart show an amount against a different age vs my table

Tags: graph, bar-chart, excel-charts

I have created a table (see below) As you can see, at age 74 there is a $2.5m withdrawal of money. But the chart (see below) shows this occurring at age 74.

This happens for all of the withdrawals, which are picking up the year before as the age and putting this in the graph.

How would I correct this please as I have never come across this before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[The table of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a4qz.png)

[The graph of the same data with the incorrect age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htUJS.png)

Here you can see the actual information for the bar on the graph.

The same graph showing the label info for the bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgnOH.png)

I have tried looking at the tick marks and axis options, but this has not changed anything.
I have tried looking at the chart range but still no luck.